# WaitForSingleObject freezing application

Tags: c++, windows, kernel, driver

I have a kernel driver detecting process creation, with an application to display the results. I am using `WaitForSingleObject(event, INFINITE)` to detect the process creation.

It worked fine in console application, but when I added it into a GUI application, the whole application froze. I suspect that it was due to `WaitForSingleObject`, and after some googling, I tried using `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` but it did not work out.

Edit: I am using C++ Windows Forms application

I have to keep on waiting as I am monitoring "forever" and not just for a one-off event..

I can provide codes or more info if you need,
Will appreciate any form of help, thanks!

I have done the following in my header file of my C++ winform app:

*take note that `myEvent = ::OpenEventW(....);`

```
while (true)
{
    switch (::MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(
        1, &myEvent, FALSE,
        INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT)
    )
    {
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
        {
            //do my stuff (send IOCTL to driver and stuff)
        }

        case (WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1):
        {
            if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
            {
                ::TranslateMessage(&msg);
                ::DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

However, it keeps going to the default part of the switch. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you post what code you have tried you are much more likely to get some help. This should help, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: sorry! i have edited my post by adding in the code which i have tried! thanks :) @IanAuld

Comment: @winston: You've basically edited your question to make a new question. People won't notice that - the "old" question already has answers. If you have a new question, ask it, but do add a link back to this question using `[link text](URL)`.

Comment: You need to [peek out all the messages, not just one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461378/understanding-msgwaitformultipleobjects/1461541#1461541).

Answer (score 3):

`MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` definitely works, but you have to understand *how* it works. It will return either the event or the message that arrives. And the messages are what's needed to keep your app from freezing. But you have to process that message:

```
GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0);
TranslateMessage(&msg);
DispatchMessage(&msg);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is C++ and MFC GUI app, there's a loop in the internal code that retrieves the messages and makes the calls into the functions that you supply in your C++ main code to handle the windows messages ( the equivalent of GetMessage() ... DispatchMessage() in a C windows program ) . If the thread does a Wait...(), then that loop is stopped.

One possible work around would be to spawn a thread and have it do the Wait...()'s and optionally send windows messages to the main thread, so that the regular message handling interface could continue to be used with your "helper" thread.

I'm not sure of the details, but someone here might be able to help, or perhaps as msdn forums or perhaps a msdn article.

Comment: Whether it's MFC, Qt or anything similar, on Windows you'll have that message loop (aka "message pump").