# Print to PDF causes my main application to hang in WaitForSingleObject call

Tags: c++, printing, mfc, waitforsingleobject

We have this application that uses mshtml.dll & rundll.32.exe to print a particular data. In Windows 10, if I select "Microsoft Print to PDF" or "Microsoft XPS Document Writer" as the printer, my application hangs. When I end the task through Task Manager, only then that the "Save Print Output As" dialog shows up. In an actual printer, there is no problem.

Here is the code snippet for it.

```
parameter.Format(_T("%s\\mshtml.dll,PrintHTML \"%s\""), systemPath, strHtmlFileName);

SHELLEXECUTEINFO shPrintInfo = {0};
shPrintInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
shPrintInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
shPrintInfo.hwnd = hWnd;
shPrintInfo.lpVerb = NULL;
shPrintInfo.lpFile = _T("rundll32.exe");        
shPrintInfo.lpParameters = parameter;   
shPrintInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
shPrintInfo.nShow = SW_NORMAL;
shPrintInfo.hInstApp = NULL; 

ShellExecuteEx(&shPrintInfo);

if (shPrintInfo.hProcess != NULL)
{
::WaitForSingleObject(shPrintInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
::CloseHandle(shPrintInfo.hProcess);
}
```

I have isolated the code where the application hangs and it's in the WaitForSingleObject() call. It never ends and it is blocking the "Save Print Output As" dialog from showing up.  If I change INFINITE to lets say 10000 (10seconds), "Save Print Output As" dialog shows up but if I test the printout on an actual printer and waitout the 10second time, there will be no data printed as the handle or process was closed by the CloseHandle() call.

Hope you could help me.

Looking at MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx as suggested by Jonathan Potter, i found a solution by following this thread
[Understanding MsgWaitForMultipleObjects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461378/understanding-msgwaitformultipleobjects)

Comment: [What’s the guidance on when to use rundll32? Easy: Don’t use it](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130104-00/?p=5643).

Comment: Just a guess, but it's possible a DDE message is involved and your wait is failing to process messages. You could try changing to `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` to run a message loop while waiting for the process to return.

Comment: Another explanation is that the dialog actually shows up but is hidden behind a window that cannot be moved out of the way since its owner thread is dead to the world, blocking on WFSO.

Comment: I've followed Jonathan Potter's suggestion to use MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx based from another thread and that solved my problem. Thank you!